# Multiple DropDownList in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, drop-down-menu

I am having 5 dropdownlist in view. I want to open and close that drodownlist(UIView) as : 

1. if I click on 1st button it will open the dropdownlist and secondtime click on that it will close.
2. if the one dropdownlist is open on 1st button click and i click on 2nd button then the 1st dropdownlist will close and 2nd dropdownlist will be open.
i am able to open and close the dropdownlist as (1). but in 2nd case i am not able. 
here is my code.

```
 if ([self.DropDownView  isDescendantOfView:self.view])
{


       [self dropDownCloseAnimation:sender withTF:nil];
        [self.DropDownView removeFromSuperview];
//        [self performSelector:@selector(showMenu:)  withObject:sender afterDelay:0.1];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.SinupView addSubview:self.DropDownView];
        [self dropDownAnimation:sender withTF:nil];
    }
```

here is the functions of animate dropdownlist

```
    -(void)dropDownCloseAnimation : (UIButton *)sender withTF : (UITextField *)textField
{
    if (sender.tag == 203 || textField.tag == 106)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 animations:^{
            self.DropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(self.TFVehicalType.frame.origin.x, self.TFVehicalType.frame.origin.y + self.TFVehicalType.frame.size.height + 2, self.TFVehicalType.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 204 || textField.tag == 107)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.DropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(self.TFVehicalColor.frame.origin.x, self.TFVehicalColor.frame.origin.y + self.TFVehicalColor.frame.size.height + 2, self.TFVehicalColor.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 205 || textField.tag == 112)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.DropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(self.TFCity.frame.origin.x, self.TFCity.frame.origin.y + self.TFCity.frame.size.height + 2, self.TFCity.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 206 || textField.tag == 113)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.DropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(self.TFLocation.frame.origin.x, self.TFLocation.frame.origin.y + self.TFLocation.frame.size.height + 2, self.TFLocation.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
    else if (sender.tag == 207 || textField.tag == 114)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.DropDownView.frame = CGRectMake(self.TFStatus.frame.origin.x, self.TFStatus.frame.origin.y + self.TFStatus.frame.size.height + 2, self.TFStatus.frame.size.width, 0);
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand right, you have 5 dropdowns, and if you click on one and some other one is open you want to close it?

Comment: yes. it's right. and i am having only one view to open not the different for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- make an array

2- add each dropdown to the array after you display it on the screen

3- in the action when you press to open/close any dropdown, make a loop on the array we just did

4- and close each drop down on each iteration

5- open the sender one.

Happy coding!

Comment: any idea other then for loop?

Comment: put each one in the .h and call and close them. does this help you?

Comment: i am having only one view not the different view for each. i just add that view in viewcontroller using animation with respect to its button frame. see my question. it's having close animation code..same while i am coded for open view.

Comment: you have one view with 5 ojects in it. arent these objects views? arent the dropdown list a view?

Answer (score 0):

You Should use your logic as given follow ,

```
-(void)btn1Click{
    Dropdown1Show=Yes;
    DropDown2Show=NO;
    DropDown3Show =NO;
    DropDown4Show=NO;
    }
    -(void)btn2Click{
    Dropdown1Show=NO;
    DropDown2Show=YES;
    DropDown3Show =NO;
    DropDown4Show=NO;
    }
    -(void)btn3Click{
    Dropdown1Show=NO;
    DropDown2Show=NO;
    DropDown3Show =YES;
    DropDown4Show=NO;
    }
    -(void)btn4Click{
    Dropdown1Show=NO;
    DropDown2Show=NO;
    DropDown3Show =NO;
    DropDown4Show=YES;
    }
```

Comment: i am having only one view for all 5 button to open dropdownlist

Comment: @ios developer But you had created five objects for five dropdowns right ? If Yes so Where I wrote Yes Inialize it and where No set nil to it Okay ?

Comment: @ios developer Hope you got an idea from it. If your problem is solved then please mark answer Correct

Comment: no i am not creating five different object for all. i am added view at runtime and create only one object for that.

Comment: @iosdeveloper Please Share the code of Question properly by which I can give you solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117403/discussion-between-ios-developer-and-sagar-shirbhate).

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to do this like you can use one dropdownlist for all and on tap of button change frame of it along with datasource. You can use tag property to differentiate between buttons and dropdownlist. In that way you can reuse your code and easily handle data flow.

thanks

Comment: that i have done. but i want to open only one dropdown at a time. that i dnt figure out.

Comment: it will only show one dropdown at a time as there is no other object. you have to handle this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
This Drop down will help You.
https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown
```

Comment: it's a good controller but its work with only one dropdown not for multiple.. as my requirement

Comment: Create how many buttons u have that many objects eg:-NIDropDown *dropDown,*dropDown2;so it will open all drop downs.